# Leaflet: How can I make my div read my LatLng?

Tags: html, string, leaflet

var info = L.control();

```
    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
                    this._div.innerHTML = (e.latlng.toString());
    };

    info.addTo(map);
```

I want my HTML div box to display my "e.latlng".

```
this._div.innerHTML = (e.latlng.toString());
```

is the line I'm having issues with.

I've tried a few variations, but I'm not sure why it's not working?

Comment: You'll need to show some more code, especially HTML.

Comment: I just updated question, thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: you've created a function which takes one argument "props", which you don't use in your function. Instead you use a undefined variable "e". Assuming "props" holds your latlng object you would need to use props.latlng.toString(). Second problem:

```
this._div.innerHTML = (e.latlng.toString());
```

You're not returning the value of e.latlng.toString(). You are evaluating if e.latlng.toString() returns something, if so it returns true, if not it returns false. If you leave out the parentheses like so:

```
this._div.innerHTML = e.latlng.toString();
```

this._div.innerHTML will be assigned with the return value of e.latlng.toString(). But since "e" is undefined it will always return false.